# Simple Explanation for PATINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I have have been reading up on PATINDEX attempting to understand what and why. I understand the when using the wildcards it will return an INT as to where that character(s) appears/starts. So:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%b%', '123b') -- returns 4
```

However I am looking to see if someone can explain the reason as to why you would use this in a simple(ish) way. I have read some other forums but it just is not sinking in to be honest.

Comment: Plenty of uses for it, generally used in combination with other functions. You could use it to help strip numbers from a string by using a combination of Patindex('%[0-9]%', string), Stuff and while clauses. There's plenty of reasons to use it, maybe you'll understand it better when you're presented with a problem that requires its use to solve it

Comment: Lets say you want to cut a string from where a certain character appears.`SELECT LEFT('123x45',PATINDEX('%x%','123x45')-1)` you pass to the LEFT function the position where x will be so it will know where to "cut"

Comment: Thank you for the comments, It has helped my understand as to how the PATINDEX function works Mihai.                                                                        Christian Barron, thank you for the explanation this aided me in reading and understand the bit of script I am currently looking at.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for realistic use-cases? I can think of two, real-life use-cases that I've had at work where `PATINDEX()` was my best option.

I had to import a text-file and parse it for `INSERT INTO` later on. But these files sometimes had numbers in this format: `00000-59`. If you try `CAST('00000-59' AS INT)` you'll get an error. So I needed code that would parse `00000-59` to `-59` but also `00000159` to `159` etc. The `-` could be anywhere, or it could simply not be there at all. This is what I did:

```
DECLARE @my_var VARCHAR(255) = '00000-59', @my_int INT

SET @my_var = STUFF(@my_var, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @my_var)-1, '')
SET @my_int = CAST(@my_var AS INT)
```

`[^0]` in this case means *"any character that **isn't** a `0`"*. So `PATINDEX()` tells me when the 0's end, regardless of whether that's because of a `-` or a number.

The second use-case I've had was checking whether an [IBAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) number was correct. In order to do that, any letters in the IBAN need to be changed to a corresponding number (A=10, B=11, etc...). I did something like this (incomplete but you get the idea):

```
SET @i = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @IBAN)
WHILE @i <> 0 BEGIN
  SET @num = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@IBAN, @i, 1))-55
  SET @IBAN = STUFF(@IBAN, @i, 1, CAST(@num AS VARCHAR(2))
  SET @i = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @IBAN)
END
```

So again, I'm not concerned with finding exactly the letter `A` or `B` etc. I'm just finding anything that isn't a number and converting it.

Comment: Wow...... many thanks for that. This has really clarified things for me. I shall be stealing this answer and saving this for future reference. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

[`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) is roughly equivalent to [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) except that it returns the position of a pattern instead of single character. Examples:

Check if a string contains at least one digit:

```sql
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'Hello') -- 0
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'H3110') -- 2
```

Extract numeric portion from a string:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING('12345', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', '12345'), 100) -- 12345
SELECT SUBSTRING('x2345', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'x2345'), 100) -- 2345
SELECT SUBSTRING('xx345', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'xx345'), 100) -- 345
```

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation, this has cleared things up. Ironically the bit of script i have been looking at has been using SUBSTRING so this has helped me out alot. Thanks again Salman.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [**PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

> The following example uses `%` and `_` wildcards to find the position at
>   which the pattern `'en'`, followed by any one character and `'ure'` starts
>   in the specified string (index starts at 1):

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%en_ure%', 'please ensure the door is locked');
```

> Here is the result set.

```
8
```

---

You'd use the `PATINDEX` function when you want to know at which character position a pattern begins in an expression of a valid text or character data type.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this example, it has helped me with my understanding. I believe this may have been one of the examples i have already read. Thank you Jodrell :).